# Run android app on galaxy s2

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, galaxy

As part of my final project in B.Sc I need to develop in android.
I complete this stages:

1. buy galaxy s2 android 4.0.4(ics).
2. installed eclipse last ver (juno).
3. installed sdk ver 20.
4. installed adk last ver+ DDMS.
5. installed kies for phone drivers.
6. run this small app on the emulator.
   [simple Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Android/article.html#tutorial_temperature)
7. turn on USB debugging.
8. connect the phone to the computer the computer recognized the pone.

**failed:**

1. run the program on the phone(the emulator is starting instead of).
2. debugging the program while the phone is connected to the computer.

Comment: Also Install Device Driver.. then run again Failed Task...

Comment: I think you are using Windows Pc? Is your phone is showing in your Device tab in Eclipse with some number or its showing as ????????????????

Answer (score 1):

Set up your system to detect your device.
If you're developing on Windows, you need to install a USB driver for adb. For an installation guide and links to OEM drivers, see the OEM USB Drivers document.
If you're developing on Mac OS X, it just works. Skip this step.
If you're developing on Ubuntu Linux, you need to add a udev rules file that contains a USB configuration for each type of device you want to use for development. In the rules file, each device manufacturer is identified by a unique vendor ID, as specified by the ATTR{idVendor} property.

check this link: http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

Answer (score 0):

Follow This tutorial it may help you [Here is the LINK](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html)

Samsung has a separate driver for connecting their Android devices for to Windows machines. I think there is an option in Kies to install this

Comment: Samsung Kies tools didn't help me.